# Add Markers by country name leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet

I am on Rstudio, and I want to add a marker based on country name.

The variable that contain the number of occurence per country is cnt_country which is in the table below

```
Morocco                            57381
France                             35729
Tunisia                            85563
Saudi Arabia                       10816
Turkey                             6725
```

However, when I use leaflet(cnt_country)%>% addTiles()%>% addMarkers() I get an error: cannot infer lat long information.

Is there a way for leaflet to add markers based on country name?

Comment: I don;t believe so, you would have to build a country-latlon lookup table and use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `leaflet` to locate the markers on the map, you'll need to provide geocoordinates. If you don't mind pinning the markers to the capital city of each country, you could get those geocoordinates from the `world.cities` data frame in the `maps` package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)
library(maps)

# ingest your data
cnt_country <- read.table(text = "Morocco,57381\nFrance,35729\nTunisia,85563\nSaudi Arabia,10816\nTurkey,6725",
                          sep = ",",
                          header = FALSE,
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                          col.names = c("country", "n"))

# import the world.cities data frame from 'maps'
data(world.cities)

# merge the desired cols from that data frame with yours by country
df <- world.cities %>%
    filter(capital == 1) %>%
    dplyr::select(country = country.etc, lat, lng = long) %>%
    left_join(cnt_country, ., by = "country")

# now map the result
leaflet(df)%>%
    addTiles()%>%
    addMarkers(label = ~n)
```